# What should I use to get the following maven report?

Tags: maven, report

How can I generate this kind of report for my project?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/dependencies.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the exact plugin dependencies for which are listed by your link: the [dependencies plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

In particular its [analyze-report](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-report-mojo.html) plugin.

In its primitive form you would:

1) Add this to your project:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

2) run this command: `mvn dependency:analyze-report`

The resulting report `dependency-analysis.html` will be located in `target` folder.

Or run `mvn site` to get a full site.

Comment: Any way to combine these reports in a multi-module project together?

Comment: `dependency:analyze-report` will only generate the dependency report without licensing info. Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261978/418439 will do.

Comment: I don't think `<executions/>` part is necessary here; it works without that as well.

Answer (score 11):

The goal is called [project-info-reports:dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) (part of the [Project Info Reports Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/)).